# Modbus TCP Remote Port

Tags: tcp, port, ethernet, modbus

I am using freemodbus library for stm32f4 for modbus slave device.

I have a problem with Modbus TCP remote port connection, When I powered up slave device, and connect to Modbus master PC than they communicate successfully, Than I unplug the ethernet cable from the modbus master side and they couldnt communicate with each other, When I analyse the problem I get very interesting information.

When I unplug the cable and connect again for PC. PC change remote port every time, so slave dont know `prvxMBTCPPortAccept` call back, calling every exceptable port request than, I analyse the `pxPCBClient` not null because of the before connection, and it doesnt clean after master port changing so everytime pxPCBClient != NULL than modbus TCP states contunie very interesting, pxPCB information have new connection request info when I compare

`pxPCBClient->remote_port` and `pxPCB->remote_port` Client remote port has before successfuly port information forever and pxPCB->remote_port changing every PC changing port.

How Can I solve this problem ? When I unplug the cable and connect again how to slave connect again ? Please help me

When I initlize the modbus TCP accept callback I used like this line:

```
tcp_accept( pxPCBListenNew, prvxMBTCPPortAccept );
```

And prvxMBTCPPortAccept function:

```
err_t prvxMBTCPPortAccept( void *pvArg, struct tcp_pcb *pxPCB, err_t xErr )
{
    err_t           error;

    if( xErr != ERR_OK )
    {
        return xErr;
    }
     SerialPrint("\nPCBClient Port : %d\n",pxPCBClient->remote_port);
     SerialPrint("pxPCB Port : %d\n",pxPCB->remote_port);

    /* We can handle only one client. */
    if( pxPCBClient == NULL )
    {
        /* Register the client. */
        pxPCBClient = pxPCB;

        /* Set up the receive function prvxMBTCPPortReceive( ) to be called when data
         * arrives.
         */
        tcp_recv( pxPCB, prvxMBTCPPortReceive );

        /* Register error handler. */
        tcp_err( pxPCB, prvvMBTCPPortError );

        /* Set callback argument later used in the error handler. */
        tcp_arg( pxPCB, pxPCB );

        /* Reset the buffers and state variables. */
        usTCPBufPos = 0;

#ifdef MB_TCP_DEBUG
        vMBPortLog( MB_LOG_DEBUG, "MBTCP-ACCEPT", "Accepted new client %d.%d.%d.%d\r\n",
                    ip4_addr1( &( pxPCB->remote_ip ) ),
                    ip4_addr2( &( pxPCB->remote_ip ) ),
                    ip4_addr3( &( pxPCB->remote_ip ) ), ip4_addr4( &( pxPCB->remote_ip ) ) );
#endif

        error = (int8_t)ERR_OK;
    }
    else
    {
        prvvMBPortReleaseClient( pxPCB );
        error = (int8_t)ERR_OK;
    }
    return error;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The master connects to the slave. (It seems that you try to do the opposite)
- The master is the client and the slave is the server.
- The server listens for connections usually on Modbus port 502 and the client connects to this server port
- The port that the client uses to connect does not matter, it is usually a high port number, normally greater than 10000, it is automatically assigned by the operating system and it changes each time it connects.
- The server should not filter by client port number, it should accept any client port number